# Conditional reopening of a form that have been closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have built a program that is based on users being logged in to use. And I have a `mainform` and a `userhandling` form. How do I trigger the `userform` if none is logged in?

My `mainform` is called from `Program.cs` and in the init of the class I check if there is no user logged in. If that is the case I open the `userform` where a user can login. When he is logged in, the form is closed and he/she can use the `mainform`. Now, the problem appears when a user logs out. I store the logged in users in a list on the `mainform` so I can sense if a user is logged in or not (my program can have multiple users logged in at the same time) but I want some sort of loop that doesn't occupy the whole program that automatically opens the `userform` again if my "userlist" is empty.

I'm just looking for ideas on how to solve this. Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Added a picture of a programflow to help simplify the issue:
[image]

1. The program is opened for the first time. No user is logged in so opens the userhandling form
2. The userhandling form is opened. When user is done and locks the app, it goes to step 3
3. In this step, I want to automaticly send the user to the userhandlingform, since I dont want the user to use the mainform without beeing logged in. What I dont know here is how to reopen the userhandling form.
4. Userhandlingform is open ready to take a new login.

I'd like to go something like:

```
while(user is logged in && no userhandlingform is open) { show userhandlingform }
```

but since its a winforms app, which is navigated through different types of components I dont know where and how to achieve this. Is this such a rare thing to want to do? Am I facing this the wrong way?

Comment: More than one user logged in in a winforms program ? Is it run from a network ? How is the authentication implemented ? It sounds more like a website than a desktop application.

Comment: Yes, more than one user can be logged in. Im using a collection of users, and each user can activate his/her session by using a password and when the user is done, the idea is to have the app locked. It is run from a network yes, in a way. Multiple instances of the app are using the same database. I dont know what you mean by authitentication. The authentication towards the databse is the normal sqlauth (not the windows one) and authentication towards the users is checked from a table in the databse. Its not a website, its  a desktop app :)

Comment: Why is the question downrated? Is something wrong with it?